# How to import data from cloud firestore to the local emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want to be able to run cloud functions locally and debug against a copy from the production data.
Is there a way to copy the data that is online to the local firestore emulator?

Comment: Please don't import your production database for testing. You are potentially exposing all your clients' personal data when you do this. Instead, create sanitized staging data.

Comment: I think that he is talking about the dev data in Firestore :)

Answer (score 230, accepted):

This can be accomplished through a set of commands in terminal on the existing project:

**1. Login to firebase and Gcloud:**

```
firebase login
gcloud auth login
```

**2. See a list of your projects and connect to one:**

```
firebase projects:list
firebase use your-project-name

gcloud projects list
gcloud config set project your-project-name
```

**3. Export your production data to gcloud bucket with chosen name:**

```
gcloud firestore export gs://your-project-name.appspot.com/your-choosen-folder-name
```

**4. Now copy this folder to your local machine, I do that in functions folder directly:**

Note : Don't miss the dot ( **.** ) at the end of below command

```
cd functions
gsutil -m cp -r gs://your-project-name.appspot.com/your-choosen-folder-name .
```

**5. Now we just want to import this folder. This should work with the basic command, thanks to latest update from Firebase team https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2519.**

```
firebase emulators:start --import ./your-choosen-folder-name
```

Check out my article on Medium about it and a shorthanded script to do the job for you https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-import-production-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator-e82ae1c6ed8

*Note: Its better to use a different bucket for it, as copying into your project bucket will result in the folder created in your firebase storage.

If you are interested in gsutil arguments like `-m`, you can see them described by executing `gsutil --help`.*

Comment: when I import thr data it take longer than 30000ms so the emulator does not run. Is there a way around this timeout?

Comment: do you mean that you get error while running this command:  `firebase emulators:start --import your-choosen-folder-name ?` can you share error message ? Just to see if firebase is throwing time out or its some kind internal time out that we can increase.

Comment: Quick note, there is currently a bug with gsuit when running python 3.8. using the -m flag will crash it, you can either run it with python 3.7 or run without the flag -m.

Comment: updated with shorter version, no metadata renaming required longer, see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/2519.

Comment: to make sure to install the Google Cloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)  and the Firebase CLI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) before begin.

Comment: anyone else getting `Error adding trigger: FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 500, [object Object]` with this approach?

Comment: If you use the do not specify a folder name this does not work on a windows machine due to the ":" in the folder name.  You need to rename the folder first using this method.  Step 3.5 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544141/10222449

Comment: Just to piggyback on this in case it helps someone: Since I can never remember the names of the buckets, I make a dir on my local with the same name and add it to gitignore.  Then I have a function `getBucket() { gsutil -m cp -r gs://${PWD##*/} .; }` so that I can just go into the dir and run getBucket to sync the data, then start the emulator with the latest file that was synced using the same command listed above `firebase emulators:start --import <<latest file name>>`

Comment: As a Mac user I had to add the following option to make it work: `gsutil -m -o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=1" cp -r gs://your-project-name.appspot.com/your-choosen-folder-name .` That disables multiprocessing.

Comment: gcloud config set project your-project-name is asking me to key in the project ID instead. So it should be gcloud config set project your-project-id

Comment: Note that there is some unknown arbitrary limit to the size of the dataset you can import into the emulators. I tried with a 1.5gb database and the emulator hung/crashed every time even with 64gb of ram. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3929

Comment: Seems it no longer wants a folder: : is a directory ⚠ Script exited unsuccessfully (code 126)

Comment: Is there a free alternative to this? This seems to require the blaze plan

Comment: For me instead of `gsutil -m cp -r gs://your-project-name.appspot.com/your-choosen-folder-name .` I had to do `gsutil -m cp -r gs://your-choosen-folder-name .` Completely leaving off the the project and appspot of the URL and instead only the bucket name.

Comment: has something changed lately? I'm getting an error : com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException: Message missing required fields: kind_info[0].kind

Comment: Billing is required to import/export data from firestore

Answer (score 29):

My method is somewhat manual but it does the trick. I've shared it in [this useful Github thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1167#issuecomment-648580480) but I'll list the steps I did here if you find them useful:

1. Go to my local Firebase project path.
2. Start the emulators using: `firebase emulators:start`
3. Create manually some mockup data using the GUI at http://localhost:4000/firestore using the buttons provided: *+ Start Collection* and *+ Add Document*.
4. Export this data locally using:  `emulators:export ./mydirectory`
5. About the project data located at *Firebase Database / Cloud Firestore*, I exported a single collection like this: `gcloud firestore export gs://my-project-bucket-id.appspot.com --collection-ids=myCollection` The export is now located under *Firebase Storage* in a folder with a timestamp as name (I didn't use a prefix for my test)
6. Download this folder to local drive with: `gsutil cp -r gs://my-project-bucket-id.appspot.com/myCollection ./production_data_export` NOTE: I did this in a Windows environment... *gsutil* will throw this error: *"OSError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"* if the folder has invalid characters for a folder name in Windows (i.e. colons) or this error: *"OSError: Invalid argument.9.0 B]"* if an inner file in the folder has invalid characters too. To be able to download the export locally, rename these with a valid Windows name (i.e. removing the colons) like this: `gsutil mv gs://my-project-bucket-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86152 gs://my-project-bucket-id.appspot.com/myCollection`
7. Once downloaded, imitate the local export structure renaming the folder to `firestore_export` and copying the `firebase-export-metadata.json` file from the local export folder. Just to be visual, here's the structure I got:

```
$ tree .
.
├── local_data_export
│   ├── firebase-export-metadata.json
│   └── firestore_export
│       ├── all_namespaces
│       │   └── all_kinds
│       │       ├── all_namespaces_all_kinds.export_metadata
│       │       └── output-0
│       └── firestore_export.overall_export_metadata
└── production_data_export
    ├── firebase-export-metadata.json
    └── firestore_export
        ├── all_namespaces
        │   └── kind_myCollection
        │       ├── all_namespaces_kind_myCollection.export_metadata
        │       ├── output-0
        │       └── output-1
        └── firestore_export.overall_export_metadata

8 directories, 9 files
```

8. Finally, start the local emulator pointing to this production data to be imported: `firebase emulators:start --import=./mock_up_data/production_data_export/`
9. You should see the imported data at: http://localhost:4000/firestore/

This should assist readers for now, while we await a more robust solution from the Firebase folks.

Comment: This actually works! The only quirk I came across is exporting Firestore - it wouldn't export my collection contents - just an empty collection. I left off the -collection-ids flag and just exported everything and it worked

Comment: Exporting only the database can be quite useless without authentication userdata. To do so use in your local project terminal: % firebase auth:export accounts.json --format=json. See also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Comment: Small note: In step #4, the entire command is `firebase emulators:export ./mydirectory`. I know it's obvious, but I did get confused for a minute.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [firestore-backup-restore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore) to export and import your production data as JSON files.

I wrote a quick hack to allow for importing these JSON in the Firebase Simulator Firestore instance.

I proposed a pull request and made this [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@crapougnax/firestore-export-import) in the meantime.

You can use it this way:

```js
const firestoreService = require('@crapougnax/firestore-export-import')
const path = require('path')

// list of JSON files generated with the export service
// Must be in the same folder as this script
const collections = ['languages', 'roles']

// Start your firestore emulator for (at least) firestore
// firebase emulators:start --only firestore

// Initiate Firebase Test App
const db = firestoreService.initializeTestApp('test', {
   uid: 'john',
   email: 'john@doe.com',
})

// Start importing your data
let promises = []
try {
   collections.map(collection =>
      promises.push(
         firestoreService.fixtures(
            path.resolve(__dirname, `./${collection}.json`),
            [],
            [],
            db,
         ),
      ),
   )
   Promise.all(promises).then(process.exit)
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err)
}
```

Obviously, since this data won't persist in the emulator, you'll typically inject them in the before() function of your test suite or even before every test.

Comment: I couldn't get through getting fireestoer-export-import to work as it seems like it has some outdated dependencies and fails when installed globally to use the script in \bin or trying to build the cloned repo on windows.

Comment: Follow up; cloned the old repo; deleted the reference to `@google-cloud/firestore` in package.json as suggested in the comments; and I can build it with `npm run build` and then `node ./build/index.js` to export the info.

Answer (score 9):

you can use [fire-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fire-import) npm package. for importing both `firestore` and `firebase storage`

Comment: This is good answer. It is the only way I have found to export the storage as well. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 8):

I was able to make some npm scripts to import from remote to local emulator and vice-versa.

```
"serve": "yarn build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore --import=./firestore_export",
"db:update-local-from-remote": "yarn db:backup-remote && gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export .",
"db:update-remote-from-local": "yarn db:backup-local && yarn db:backup-remote && gsutil -m cp -r ./firestore_export gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com && yarn run db:import-remote",
"db:import-remote": "gcloud firestore import gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export",
"db:backup-local": "firebase emulators:export --force .",
"db:rename-remote-backup-folder": "gsutil mv gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export_$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M)",
"db:backup-remote": "yarn db:rename-remote-backup-folder && gcloud firestore export gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export"
```

So you can export the local Firestore data to remote with:

```sh
npm db:update-remote-from-local
```

Or to update your local Firestore data with remote one, do:

```sh
npm db:update-local-from-remote
```

These operations will backup the remote Firestore data, making a copy of it and storing it on Firebase Storage.

Comment: "db:update-local-from-remote": "yarn db:backup-remote && gsutil -m cp -r gs://my-firebase-bucket.appspot.com/firestore_export .",
How does this import to emulator db?

Comment: Sorry, the list of commands was missing the "serve" one, which starts the emulator with --import options. Thus after running `db:update-local-from-remote` you just need to restart your emulators. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/1968

Comment: How can we run the db:update-local-from-remote script? Is this meant to be running from gcloud, firebase or some other program?

Comment: to you from your local environment

Comment: failing because of this file : firebase-export-metadata.json

Comment: I had to use `gsutil rsync` instead of `gsutil cp`

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in way to copy data from a cloud project to the local emulator. Since the emulator doesn't persist any data, you will have to re-generate the initial data set on every run.

Answer (score 4):

I was about to go add a cli option to [`firebase-tools`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) but pretty happy with the [`node-firestore-import-export`](https://github.com/jloosli/node-firestore-import-export) package.

```sh
yarn add -D node-firestore-import-export
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "db:export": "firestore-export -a ./serviceAccountKey.json -b ./data/firestore.json",
    "db:import": "firestore-import -a ./serviceAccountKey.json -b ./data/firestore.json",
    "db:emulator:export": "export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 && yarn db:export",
    "db:emulator:import": "export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 && yarn db:import",
    "db:backup": "cp ./data/firestore.json ./data/firestore-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M).json",
    "dev": "firebase emulators:start --import=./data --export-on-exit=./data",
  },
```

You will need to create a service account in the firebase console.

You can replace the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable with hard coded values.

```sh
open https://console.firebase.google.com/project/$GCLOUD_PROJECT/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk
mv ~/Downloads/myProjectHecticKeyName.json ./serviceAccountKey.json
```

That being said the [`gcloud`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) tools are definitely the way to go in production, as you will need s3 backups anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to import data to local storage from Google Cloud Storage without any commands:

- export Firestore to Google cloud storage bucket by clicking **More in google cloud**
- choose your desired file in **google cloud storage bucket**
- **open terminal**  (Google terminal shell near the search bar)
  in terminal click **Open editor**
  right click on desired file in online VSCode and click **download**.

You shoud start downloading of .tar file which is in fact your exported data from firestore.

- Create a folder in your root (as example you may call it 'firestore-local-data')
- Copy paste (or unarchive data) to this folder from archive file .tar
- run `firebase emulators:start --import ./firestore-local-data`
  This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script to able to do that:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const collections = ['albums', 'artists'];
let rawData: any;
    
for (const i in collections) {
    rawData = fs.readFileSync(`./${collections[i]}.json`);
    const arr = JSON.parse(rawData);

    for (const j in arr) {
        db.collection(collections[i]).add(arr[j])
        .then(val => console.log(val))
        .catch(err => console.log('ERRO: ', err))
    }
        
}
```