# `gsutil cp` command throwing "OSError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud, gsutil

I've followed the [gsutil install guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) following the Google Cloud instructions and I've [updated GCloud components](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) to the latest versions. I've just recently installed and configured GCloud to work with my credentials and project. First, I've used the following command to export a single collection I need from my *Firestore* :

```
gcloud firestore export gs://my-project-id.appspot.com --collection-ids=theCollectionINeed
```

Now I see this export is in my Firebase Console *Storage* section as a folder. Being the project *Owner*, I'd like to get this export into my local system. For that, I see I need to use *gsutil* to be able to copy it. Reading the instructions to [download the object from your bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#download_the_object_from_your_bucket), I've tried with the following command, but I got this error:

```
$ gsutil cp -r gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154 .
Copying gs://lucky-level-dev-6ac34.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154.overall_export_metadata...
OSError: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I'm running this command using `cmd` in a Windows 10 environment.
I'd like to be able to download this folder from the cloud to my local drive.

### Update

After being, I tried to change the bucket folder (object prefix) as suggested:

```
gsutil mv gs://my-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154 gs://my-project-id.appspot.com/2020-06-23_someFolder
```

But trying again now throws me a new error:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://my-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22_someFolder .
Copying gs://my-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22_someFolder/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154.overall_export_metadata...
OSError: Invalid argument.9.0 B]
```

Surely I need to change the name of the file too?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that GCS object prefix includes colons and these may cause issues for Windows. I don't have Windows. Please try `gsutil mv gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154 gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/X` to rename the object and then try `gsutil cp -r gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/X .` again.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for the suggestion. Now I've surpassed that error; sadly now I got the following: `OSError: Invalid argument.9.0 B]` I'll update my question. Any ideas?

Comment: @DazWilkin I also had to rename the inner file that also included colons in its name. Thanks again!

Comment: You may wish to file a bug with Google. The command should work on supported OSs and clearly does not with Windows. https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: For anyone who is interested, this issue is fixed in `gcloud storage` (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1513)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When doing the `cp -r gs:/bucket_name/folder .` Gsutil will try to create a folder with "bucket_name" name in the current location, [Windows doesn't allow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) the name of folders to have some special characters including the ':'

You can rename the bucket folder (object prefix) with the command @DazWilkin suggested `gsutil mv gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/2020-05-22T02:01:06_86154 gs://m-project-id.appspot.com/new_folder_name` and then try again with the new folder name.

Also check that all filenames inside the directory structure don't have the ':' character or any other [special one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That really seemed to be the problem, sounds logic but now I've got the following: `OSError: Invalid argument.9.0 B]` Any ideas?

Comment: I also had to rename the inner file that also had colons and the problem was solved. Please, complement your answer with this addition to get a full answer in case someone don't read the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I am glad this has been solved! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted solution from question author to place it in the answer section)*.

All I had to do was rename the inner file that also had colons in its name. Renaming it solved the problem!

Comment: Do you _really_ think this answers the question by itself?? Don't just over moderate...

Comment: @Metafaniel: it is (partial) answer material, so it needs to go in the answer space. I am happy to delete it if you think it is trivial, or close the question as Typo/Unrepro if the answers are unlikely to be useful to future readers, but I do not think this material belongs in the question. Alternatively you can post this answer yourself (minus the attribution statement) as a self-answer and I can delete the CW copy.

Comment: Finally, you could ask a question over at _Meta Stack Overflow_ if you want to get second opinions though.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a `gcloud firestore export` the issue can be avoided by specifying a directory:

```sh
# BAD this will auto generate a directory windows doesnt like
gcloud firestore export gs://my-bucket

# GOOD specify a directory
gcloud firestore export gs://my-bucket/firestore-backup

# copy as usual
gsutil -m cp -r "gs://my-bucket/firestore-backup" .
```