# Getting error while using gsutil to download files from google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to download multiple files from google cloud CLI using `gsutil` on Windows. The command, I used is

```
C:\Users\User>gsutil -m cp -r "gs://takeout-export-c98906c8-f41d-4702-a512-8a6affaffb1c/20220608T548213Z/Resource: -5623962341676446683" .
Copying gs://takeout-export-c98906c8-f41d-4702-a512-8a6affaffb1c/20220608T548213Z/Resource: -5623962341676446683/takeout-20220608T386412Z-001.zip...
[WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: '.\\Resource: -5623962341676446683'

CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

From the admin panel, I am able to access the folder `5623962341676446683` and its contents are present. The command is working fine for other folders. Can you please let me know probable reason for this error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run the command with the debug flag `-d` to get more details about the error and update your post accordingly?
`gsutil -d -m cp gs://<path_to_file_in_bucket>`

Comment: @someRandomDev, Thanks for your response. Got the following error message in debug. 

DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     
        raise CommandException('{count} file{pl}/object{pl} could '
    gslib.exception.CommandException: CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with files / folders containing colons (or a few other characters) on Windows machines, see [issue logged here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1513) for details of a fix due for release soon.
Also see a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542242/gsutil-cp-command-throwing-oserror-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-l) and (assuming none of the files in that bucket have invalid characters) try removing the colon from the downloaded folder with

```
gsutil -m cp -r "gs://takeout-export-c98906c8-f41d-4702-a512-8a6affaffb1c/20220608T548213Z/Resource: -5623962341676446683" "Resource -5623962341676446683"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried removing the colon as suggested but it did not work. Got the following error. 
CommandException: No URLs matched:

Comment: If you take the colon out of the gs:// URL then that would explain the new error. Can you try with the exact command from the answer and reply with the full error message please.

Comment: Here an example as you requested:

gsutil -m cp -r "takeout-export-597caf5b-33a6-40ab-93e6-5bfe0caa0cfe/20230704T101720Z/Resource: -5146311862594854620" "Resource -5146311862594854620" E:\Test
CommandException: No URLs matched: takeout-export-597caf5b-33a6-40ab-93e6-5bfe0caa0cfe/20230704T101720Z/Resource: -5146311862594854620
CommandException: No URLs matched: Resource -5146311862594854620
CommandException: 2 files/objects could not be transferred.