# Telling client side to fetch from firestore emulator in dev

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I have initialized firebase in a create-react-app in a utility folder like so:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})

export default app
```

To fetch from my firebase instance I then import firebase where necessary and fetch like so:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import firebase from './utils/firebase'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  const randomElements = async (array, n) => {
    const res = await array
      .sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random())
      .slice(0, n)
    setValues(res)
  }

  const getData = async () => {
    const eachValue = []
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('customers')
      .get()
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach(doc => eachValue.push(doc.data()))
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    return randomElements(eachValue, 12)
  }

  console.log(values)

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className='App-link'
          href='https://reactjs.org'
          target='_blank'
          rel='noopener noreferrer'
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

If I have the firestore emulator running, is there a way to tell my react application to fetch from the emulator as opposed to from the production database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set your emulator to be the one to be used by your application. As clarified in the official documentation [Connect your app to the emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#connect_your_app_to_the_emulators), you need to use the below code block to point to the emulator.

```
//Initialize your Web app as described in the Get started for Web documentation
// Firebase previously initialized using firebase.initializeApp().
var db = firebase.firestore();
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
  db.settings({
    host: "localhost:8080",
    ssl: false
  });
}
```

Besides that, you can get a full tutorial on how to develop an application with emulators on Firestore using React - so you can get more information and details on how exactly do it - on this article:

- [Firebase Local Development with Firestore, Cloud Functions and React](https://medium.com/@samshapiro/firebase-local-development-with-firestore-cloud-functions-and-react-c29c188bd60e).

Comment: do you by chance have experience with seeding the emulators on start? Is there a built-in method to achieve this or do they outline it in the docs by chance?

Comment: Hi @RobertTerrell the possibility that I would think of would be to perform an import to the simulator. I would recommend you to check these links [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1167) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838764/how-to-import-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator), on ways of doing it and how it need to works like this.