# Start firebase emulator with default database filled with dummy data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Whenever I start the emulator I have to import a database for the realtime database and *sometimes* make the top level collections manually for firestore.

Is there a way to setup the emulator, such that the databases are already ready?

I don't want this to be filled with all the data from the actual project but rather some dummy data that is suffficient to carry out local development.

**Again**, I am not asking for this setup to run tests, (*as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838764/how-to-import-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator)*) but rather for daily development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to import default data when the emulator starts, have a look at the documentation on [importing and exporting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#export_and_import_emulator_data), which says:

> You can export data from the Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database and Cloud Storage emulators to use as a shareable, common baseline data set.

And the documentation for the `--import` flag:

> `--import=import_directory`
>
> Optional. Use with the Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database or Cloud Storage emulator. Import data saved using the `--export-on-exit` startup option or the emulators:export command to a running Authentication, Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database or Cloud Storage emulator instance. Any data currently in emulator memory will be [overwritten].

Comment: Edited the question to remove the stupid mistake. Will try using `--export-on-exit=` to export the next time I set things up manually and then add `--import` with the `firebase emulators:start`.
Thanks :)